# Syndication feeds using Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

How to import details from other websites using Syndication Feeds using Django. Am new to Django python. In my blog i need to use feeds concept. Please give some examples for that.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a good start: [adding RSS feeds to you Django application](http://www.rt-coding.com/blog/view/adding-rss-feeds-your-django-application.html).

Also, make sure to read the [django syndication feed framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/syndication/)